# Was the number $3,317,044,064,679,887,385,961,981$ doublechecked?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, pseudoprimes

In Wikipedia , Miller-Rabin-Test, it is mentioned that the smallest strong-Fermat pseudoprime to the prime-bases upto $41$ is $$3,317,044,064,679,887,385,961,981$$

Hence, every number smaller than this number is prime, if it passes the Rabin-Miller-test for the prime-bases upto $41$.

> Has this result been doublechecked ?
>
> How long would such a doublecheck take ? Is there a method more efficient the enumerating all numbers upto that point ?

Comment: Reference 13 in that article seems to provide the results. You're looking for another?

Comment: @John This was one calculation, right ? I am looking for a doublecheck , that means a calculation independent from the one you mentioned. Unless, your reference is already a repitition of the calculation.

Comment: So the answer is yes. :)

Comment: @John It's Wikipedia, so Peter is right to be extremely skeptical. It's very easy to invent plausible-sounding citations on Wikipedia.

Comment: @RobertSoupe Such important results should always be doublechecked (no matter what the source is). Since apparently, no shortcut is known, the high limit (about $3\cdot 10^{24}$) legitimates at least doubts. Unfortunately, this is also true for other extremely time-consuming calculations, for example, do we actually know that there is no third Wieferich prime below , lets say $10^{15}$. I am not ultrasceptical, but I also do not believe everything that is posted on some popular site.

Comment: Indeed. I started to read the referenced ArXiV paper. But way too many people don't even bother to at least click on citation links.